# How to set the syslog app-name with SyslogAppender

Tags: logback, syslog

How to set the syslog [APP-NAME](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.2.5) with a `ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender`. It seems that it's not intended.